# Prompt the user to enter only part of the password

Tags: security, authentication, hash, passwords, salt

There is an internet banking website that I use a lot and its way of authenticating users is to ask about their security question and only enter 3 random characters of their password.

I have always wondered how they store users' passwords on their system, surely it is not plain text? or is it? Also it cannot be hashed because the characters that are required for logging in changes each time. What is the idea behind it?

[image: login screen]

Comment: This sounds wrong on so many levels. It eliminates the option to use a password manager, which is the most secure way to have different, complex passwords for many sites. It makes secure password storage pretty much impossible on the backend. It is horrible user experience (even for the passwords I know, I cannot easily type given letters). Security questions are not recommended by modern standards anymore (eg. NIST 800-63). And so on... I wonder what threat this is supposed to mitigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These kind of authentication systems are intended to provide protection against keyloggers/traffic interception, on the basis that if the login details are intercepted, the attacker only gets a few characters of the password rather than the whole thing. Sadly large parts of the banking industry still use them rather than just implementing actual MFA (although that seems to be slowly improving).

You're correct that it's not possible to use this kind of authentication if the password is hashed, however that doesn't necessarily mean that it has to be stored in plain text.

Assuming that they've implemented it well, the password should be stored encrypted, rather than in plain text. There might also be an element of separation, so that the system storing the passwords is separate from the frontend that the user is interacting with, so you could have an authentication flow like this:

- The frontend makes a query to the authentication microservice with the username/ID.
- The microservice responds with which three characters it wants.
- The user is asked to input the characters.
- The frontend sends these three characters to the microservice.
- The microservice responds with a success or failure.

This way, a compromise of the frontend doesn't directly expose the users' password, and you can implement controls (such as logging and rate limiting) on the authentication microservice to help identify and protect from a compromised frontend.

Comment: Interesting to know that it is for keyloggers. But it is very insecure to know that someone can know your password, because if it is encrypted, then it can be decrypted!

Comment: @sandrows if someone has compromised your bank to the point where they can obtain both the encryption passwords and the decryption keys (and possible and KEKs used to protect those), they can probably just steal your money anyway. And if you're re-using your online banking password on other sites, it's far more likely that it'll be compromised on one of those.

It's certainly not ideal, but *assuming that the bank has solid security*, the actual risk it presents is pretty low.

Comment: It is not very effective against keyloggers as keys will be pressed anyway, and even in case of a password of 10 characters, there is a 50+% for each character to be leaked after the second observed authentication. That's very far from being a good mitigation. If keyloggers are the threat, it would be a lot more useful to use a screen keyboard. Also encryption for password storage is not secure. While you can build all kinds of mitigations around it (which these banks should do anyway), the industry standard way is to store hashes derived via appropriate KDFs. Not all threats are external.

Comment: So in short, if keyloggers are in fact the threat mitigated by this, then a lot more attack surface is presented by this solution than solved by preventing keyloggers from reading the password *in one go* (but not over multiple logins).

Comment: Also knowing the answer to a reasonably well-known question (a lot of people will know the model of a user's first car, or they can just guess), 3 characters of the password will need ~238k tries worst case - that's less than a minute unless further mitigations are in place (I guess there are, but anyway). This solution simply does not make much sense, and is not secure at all.

Comment: @GaborLengyel it's certainly not the mechanism I'd choose to implement (compared to storing a properly hashed password and using strong MFA) - but if it's implemented well it might be not terrible. The individual digits can also be used for something like telephone banking (although that has its own set of issues). The security question is just terrible though.